# Is UDP or TCP hole punching through a HTTP proxy possible?

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, udp, hole-punching

I have a Node.js program that establishes a connection to a server via UDP hole punching. However the environment I am running in currently allows connections to the internet only via a HTTP proxy. Is it still possible to perform UDP hole punching in this case, or even TCP hole punching?

A rough map of the current environment:

Computer -> Router -> Proxy -> Gateway -> Internet